# JBoss7 and Eclipselink, No Persistence provider for EntityManager

Tags: eclipselink, jboss7.x

I'm having a problem with JBoss 7.02.Final. I'm porting a project from JBoss5.1GA and (outside a fair amount of rewrites in the lookups to support EE6) I'm having a problem registering Eclipselink on the classpath. I've searched around and I see several posts saying this issue is fixed but I can't seem to find a working example.

There's a very high chance I'm doing something wrong as I'm new to EE6 development.

**The ear is built as the following**

```
  - ProductionEE6
  ./lib/eclipselink2.*.jar
  ./lib/javax.persistence.jar
    . . .
    ProductionEJB.jar
    . . .
    Production.war
```

**My persistence.xml is:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="production" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>

        <non-jta-data-source>java:/ProductionDS</non-jta-data-source>
        <class><!-- entities --></class>

        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.h2.Driver"/>
            <property name="eclipselink.target-server" value="JBoss"/> 
            <!-- A few other properties here -->
        </properties>       
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Everything boots up fine, I see the datasources, I get through security (through a custom DatabaseModule so my data-sources are definitely fine) and when I finally make a call to an EJB I see the following errors:

```
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named production
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:69) [hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.Final]
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:47) [hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.Final]
    at com.danielbchapman.production.entity.DelegateInstance.getEm(DelegateInstance.java:67) [ProductionEJB.jar:]
    at com.danielbchapman.production.entity.EntityInstance.getEm(EntityInstance.java:39) [ProductionEJB.jar:]
    at com.danielbchapman.production.beans.OptionsDao.<init>(OptionsDao.java:20) [ProductionEJB.jar:]
    ... 94 more
```

In regards to that, I'm not using a JTA DataSource so I've been handling the transactions manually. This call is the "DelegateInstance" above with the following code: *(where persistenceUnitId is "production" in this case.)*

```
/**
 * @return an instance of the entity manager if it isn't there.
 */
public EntityManager getEm()
{
    if(manager == null)
    {
        manager = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(getPersistenceUnitId())
                .createEntityManager();
    }

    return manager;
}
```

What worries me the most is seeing this on the stack:
***[hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar:1.0.1.Final]*** Obviously I'm not loading EclipseLink properly. I'm running out of ideas here so if anyone can help I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EclipseLink 2.4 will now work with JBoss AS 7.1.1 - tested and working - hth

Comment: Thanks John, I'll give the build a shot.

Comment: Sorry that took so long to test, but yes, Eclipselink 2.4 is working well with JBoss 7.1.1 now.

Answer (score 0):

According to http://dev.dzhokanov.com/?p=8:

> Furthermore, this forum thread came to support my hypothesis – http://community.jboss.org/message/623759#623759
>
> In the thread Scott Marlow (JBoss 7/JPA lead developer) admits:
>
> “You are not the only one that wants to use EclipseLink but that is not ready yet. “
>
> As far as I understand, there are some incompatibilities in the EclipseLink JPA implementation that need to be adjusted in order to be compatible with JBoss 7. So, I don’t expect Jboss 7-EclipseLink support soon.

So it might be the case that this is currently not possible at all. But if you find a way, I'd be very interested in it.

Comment: I contacted Scott directly and I'm working off the Alpha. I'm stone walled for time right now, but hopefully in the next ~ 2 weeks I'll have it up. The ALPHA will allow you to set up an Eclipselink Module, but you run into the VFS URL error that you get with JBoss 5.1 without Session Customization. Its a problem pulling a null resource for persistence.xml from the VFS. In short--I need a lot of time. Let me know you're progress.

Comment: I just changed the implementation to use Hibernate and moved on. Sorry I don't have time to help more in this issue. Good luck!